# Change the letter between two string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable `a = 'aa', 'bb'`.
How can i concatenate the strings and change the second 'a' with the first 'b'.
So the output of the code will be `'ab ba'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly basic one.

```py
def perm_concatenate(a):
  return a[0][:-1] + a[1][0] + a[0][-1] + a[1][1:]
```

Sample test:

```sh
>>> a = 'aa', 'bb'
>>> perm_concatenate(a)
'abab'
```

Note: I didn't do any kind of input control here, it's up to you op